# Saving photo in Android to sd card and show them in bitmap in other intent

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap, camera

I need a help with this Android application!
I'm at very beginning in developing on Android and for a school's project I have to create an App that scan qr's codes and shoot photo.

I have a problem on shooting photo, I'd like to shoot the photo, confirm it pressing "tick button", open a new intent that allow you to add a comment on `Image`, and then through another button I'll ad inside an `ArrayAdapter`.

I'll try to show you the parts of the code that have problem, if anything more is needed just ask!

The method `TakePhoto` is inside a `Fragment` that launch the `camera` intent pressing a button.

```
public void TakePhoto() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    int imageNum = 0;
    File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"aMuse");
    imagesFolder.mkdirs();
    String fileName = "image_" + String.valueOf(imageNum) + ".jpg";
    File output = new File(imagesFolder, fileName);
    while (output.exists()){
        imageNum++;
        fileName = "image_" + String.valueOf(imageNum) + ".jpg";
        output = new File(imagesFolder, fileName);
    }
    Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(output);

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);

    getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
}
```

The `onActivityResult` is inside a `FragmentActivity` that contains 2 more `Fragment`, and I'll need to pass the image shooted to another intent `(imageResult)` that will show the photo shooted and permit to add comment through an `EditText`.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent); 

    IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    if (scanResult != null) {
        Intent qrResult = new Intent(this, QrResult.class);
        String resultString = scanResult.getContents();
        qrResult.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, resultString);
        startActivity(qrResult);
    }
    else{
        switch (requestCode) {
        case 100:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Intent imageResult = new Intent(this, ImagePreview.class);

                startActivity(imageResult);
            }
        }
    }
```

In this situation the app (as I understood) save the photo inside SD/aMuse with name image_nn.jpg. What I need to do is get this photo and set inside imageResult as bitmap. I tried passing the uri through .putExtra method but it crash giving "null pointer exception" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this blog post I wrote on this matter can be really helpful to you:

[Guide: Android: Use Camera Activity for Thumbnail and Full Size Image](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=590)

The titles explains the content. Go over it and tell me if you have a problem after reading it.

what important to you is the full size image part.

**UPDATE:**
The problem you are facing right now:

```
 FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION ERROR
```

is not related to the way you get your image, but to the image it self, quoting android developer:

```
 The most common reason for this error is a too large IPC
```

source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/KKEyW6XdDvg/discussion

IPC (stand for: **Inter-Process Communication**) is basically the way proccesses in android comunicated, you can read more here:

http://www.slideshare.net/jserv/android-internals-30176596

And the problem you are facing derived most probably baecase your image is too big.

Back to the guide I posted, you have there this peace of code:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{  
//Check that request code matches ours:
if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_FULLSIZE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) 
{
    //Get our saved file into a bitmap object:
   File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator + "image.jpg");
   Bitmap bitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), 1000, 700);
}
```

}

for this line of code:

```
 Bitmap bitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), 1000, 700);
```

try to provide a smaller dimmensions, some thing like:

```
 Bitmap bitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), 100, 70);
```

see if this fixes your problem, and then you can play with those parameters to get your best result.

Comment: Hey there, I've tried to use your method but it return me FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION ERROR, can you help me solve it?

Comment: I've used your thumbnail method and it's working good, but I'd prefer to have a full size image, and I got the error above if i follow your guide.

Comment: Ok now it's working, any ideas for creating multiple image? My method for creating image like image_NN.jpg is not working anymore. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

In first activity:

```
fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
    fos.write(bArray);
        fos.close();
    Intent i = new Intent(ClickImg.this, CameraAct.class);
    imgPath = Uri.fromFile(output);

    System.out.println("Main Data: " +pathFile);
    i.putExtra("bytedata", pathFile);
    i.putExtra("pname", photoName);

    startActivity(i);
    this.finish();
```

In second activity:

```
           String photoName = i.getStringExtra("pname");
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoName);

    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewTest);
    myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```